# Can "Elastic Database Transactions" work from Azure Functions and/or App Services?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

The documentation on [distributed transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-transactions-overview) across multiple SQL Azure databases mentions the guest OS for environments running the transaction must have .NET 4.6.1 . Is this the case for Azure Functions and/or App Services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested the distributed transactions on Azure Web App using following code. If I throw a exception before invoke scope.Complete, the transaction will roll back and the records will not be saved to the tables. It proves that Azure App Services did support elastic database transactions.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (var conn1 = new SqlConnection(azureSqlConnStrDb1))
    {
        conn1.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = conn1.CreateCommand();
        cmd1.CommandText = string.Format("insert into T1 values(3)");
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    using (var conn2 = new SqlConnection(azureSqlConnStrDb2))
    {
        conn2.Open();
        var cmd2 = conn2.CreateCommand();
        cmd2.CommandText = string.Format("insert into T2 values(4)");
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    throw new Exception("I am a exception");
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

App Service (and Functions) are running on .NET 4.7:

[image]

(August 2017)

Comment: That might not be the same thing. Please take a look at the link.

Comment: @Sentinel I've read it and my understanding is they are the same thing. Any specific reason you think it's not?

Comment: Yes - they say that the 'guest OS' being changed on App Services is not supported. That feature for changing the .NET framework has been there for ages, so I assume that the version of the IIS process might not be the same as the .NET framework version configured on the machine